# What is the best mechanism for code integration

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have checked git flow based on Vicent's Driessen [post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and I found it very useful but maybe very complicated for my necessities on code integration.

Anyone who could know other mechanism for code integration?

Comment: This is a really broad and in my view, completely opinion-based question with no "correct" answer. Are you able to revise the question to better communicate a specific problem you're facing which you need to solve?

Comment: I agree with @MarkEmbling can you give us more information about how you build, package and deploy your code? Are you doing any kind of Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery / Continuous Deployment?